# How to create installator and get resources then

Tags: java

I created an app in Java. Now Id like to create installator for it. I know how to create JAR files but I'd like to create installator like exe files. So 2 questions:

1. As first - which program should I use to create installator. Is there any simple way to create multi-platform installator? I heard something about IzPack is it good choice for creating multi-platform installer?
2. How should I get pictures and documents in this app after creating installator? In my app it looks like: *ImageIO.read(new File("/home/me/Pictures/picture.jpg))*. Of course in some other environment there is no chance this would work. How should I get resoruces after creating installator. Maybe I should use methods: getResource(), getResourceAsStream() etc.?

Answer (score 1):

REgarding the installation, I would probably simply go for a zip file containing an executable jar or a startup shell script. Or use Java Web Start.

Regarding images, they should be in the jar file, along with your .class files, and be loaded using [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I have heard that [Apache Launcher](http://commons.apache.org/launcher/) is useful for creating an executable that runs your jar with a classpath etc.

Comment: But how to create executable jar file? I know how to run JAR file from command line but when I try to run it by clicking it opens and shows all files in it.

Comment: That means you didn't install the JRE (which creates a file association for .jar files), or that you modified this file association in order to open the jar file rather than executing it.

Comment: I have JRE.. Then I wouldnt be able to run app I have written ;) So I think its the second option. Then how to turn it to execute it rather than open?